# How can I exclude a specific folder from DFS Replication in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

Question pretty much says it all...I need to exclude a specific folder (a dropbox folder) from being included in our DFS-R setup. I see how to setup an exclusion using Server 2003, but haven't been able to find an explanation of how to do this in Server 2008.

Can somebody lend a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the DFS Management Console:

1. Highlight Replication group on the left pane of console
2. On right pane click **Replicated Folders** tab
3. Right click the folder and choose Properties
4. File and Subfolder filters are found there
   [image]

From MS: [Exclude files or subfolders from replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753409.aspx)

Comment: This looks like what I need, but how do I input the exact folder location? When I tried to do this using quotes and \'s it said those are invalid characters for that field so I thought I was looking at the wrong area. Also, the link you provided me is for Server 2003, but clearly the screenshot you posted is Server 2008.

Comment: woops, sorry, try link again. fixed for 2008. you cannot supply full paths. only the folder name (wildcard '*' is allowed though)

Comment: I suppose that'll work then, just need to make sure there aren't any other folders with the same name. Thanks for your help!