# DFSR specific folder specific server

Tags: cache, dfs, dfs-r

I'm considering using DFSR to speed up a slow link between a branch office.

I want to know if it is possible to exclude a specific folder from the replication, so that when the branch office accesses it, the data is read/written to the main server?

I would like this to be transparent to the user i.e. both offices see the same set of files.

I have a folder with several access databases, and i read that using access and DFSR makes bad things happen, so i want to limit the access databases to the main server.

My original plan was to use branch cache, but i don't have the option of upgrading to enterprise, so i'm looking for other ways to accomplish caching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude a specific folder from DFS Replication in Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/229255/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-folder-from-dfs-replication-in-server-2008)

Comment: Check the link I gave, the tab is file filter, remove access database from there

Comment: I did thanks, but what i wanted to know is if by doing that the users from the replicated side would be able to see the non replicated files as if they were replicated.

Comment: Good question, I dont think, as technically they are not on the replicated share,  but its a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you deployed DFS-N as well as DFS-R? DFS-N will allow people to see all the content inside a linked folder while DFS-R can be used to replicate the content you need replicated to the remote site.

Here is an overview of DFS-N

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730736(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As `yagmoth555` mentioned, you can exclude the folder (or file types)...

Your concern is valid, as this will create dissociated files that will be out of sync. Users going to one referral path will see different data from the others.

Since you have an entire folder structure that contains these files, it might suffice to exclude the folder (and in branch site) create a shortcut within that jumps to the hub/desired server via UNC share.